# Problem with save-current-buffer and find-file

Tags: buffers, find-file

I have a list of files that I want to successively visit with `find-file` and then return to the first buffer. I thought that `save-current-buffer` would help me to achieve this. However, with the following code, the cursor ends up in one of the buffers opened by `find-file`, not in the buffer where `save-current-buffer` had been executed:

```
(save-current-buffer
    (dolist (file org-agenda-files)
        (find-file file)
        ;; do something with file
        ))
```

How can I return to the first buffer after `find-file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1) one could enhance my code example by calling `switch-to-buffer` after `save-current-buffer` in order to jump back to the saved buffer.

```
(save-current-buffer
    (dolist (file org-agenda-files)
        (find-file file)
        ;; do something with file
        ))
(switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
```

2) one could go for YoungFrog's proposal that uses `with-current-buffer` and `find-file-noselect`:

```
(dolist (file org-agenda-files)
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
        ;; do something with file
        ))
```

In my view, both options are pretty much equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

`save-current-buffer`, like `set-buffer`, controls which buffer is the `current-buffer`.

But it does not deal with which buffers might be displayed and which windows might be selected.

`find-file` not only visits file contents in a buffer - it also displays the buffer and selects its window.

You might want **`find-file-noselect`** instead of `find-file`.

Comment: But how can I then do something within the buffer created by `find-file-noselect`? I could use `switch-to-buffer` in order to jump to this buffer, but this amounts to using `find-file`.

Comment: If you want to display a buffer, and you want to select it, then do so. If you want that then yes, `find-file` does that. Your question was about what `save-current-buffer` does. It does not take any care wrt whether a buffer is displayed or selected.

Comment: with-current-buffer together with find-file-noselect might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @YoungFrog But with `with-current-buffer` I have to know the name of the buffer that is associated with each file? Could give an example?

Comment: @Timm ffns returns the buffer. Basically you'd do (wcb (ffns ...) do things). (I'm on mobile so writing code is painful, sorry about the result)